# How to Synch two databases in Microservice architecture in CQRS separate ones for read/write

Tags: sql-server, microservices, cqrs, data-synchronization

I was asked this question in this interview:

How to Synch two database data? There will be time delays etc. How do we handle?

The background: I mentioned about Microservice architecture and also using CQRS for performance (Separate Read/get query database) and separate write command database.

Now, if the customer enters or modifies data, how it will be replicated/synched in to the read database?

I was talking about stuffs like cosmos db options etc which prevents dirty read etc. I also mentioned about cache. But I am not certain what are all variousoptions to do synch. Interviewer specifically asked me in SQL DB level how do I synch between two DBs.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and replication or synchronization of database servers is completely vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Apparently Microsoft SQL Server. I mentioned "SQL DB" level meaning I am apparently referring MS SQL :)

Comment: Every relational database is a "SQL database".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Sorry mate, I would say a SQL DB is a relational DB. I think the conversation derails. Please put on if you know the answer and some hints and thoughts :) Else we both will read other's minds :)

Comment: When using Microsoft SQL Server, the obvious approach is to use the built-in replication feature (specifically transactional replication) or else something like Always On/availability groups if you need true redundancy. Doing this entirely from client code is 1) a lot of work and 2) very hard to get right.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Thank you for the insights, I will read more about these from youtube videos.

Comment: @Learner "micro" in microservices is just branding. Syncing or replication between databases *doesn't* need any external services. All major databases offer replication features for several decades.

Comment: @Learner no, read the documentation and tutorials. You can't learn about a complex subject through a short video. If it was that easy you wouldn't need to ask in the first place

Comment: @Learner what you *can* do, is take advantage of the three months of free access to Pluralsight's courses offered through the (free) Visual Studio Dev Essentials program. You can also check Microsoft's own online courses

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Thank you, I didn't know about replication when interviewer asked me tricky lol. If he asked me what is replication I would have answered lol. I didn't know answer to synch is replication.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Regarding videos, well thats quick way to get our head around. I can not read "Complex Microsoft" MSDN docs that hardly people in the world understands. Same is with Plularsight video, I can't digest. Remember anything explained in a way that a layman can't understand, means, the tutor themselves didn't understand it well - Einstein said that. I love some of the youtube videos that (compiles/translates in a more digestable way). Also, linkedin courses are ok and so some MS videos are ok

Comment: @Learner maybe it is, maybe it isn't. The correct answer would be "what do you mean"? Replicating data between database servers is different from synchronizing data between the SQLite database in a mobile application and a database server.

Comment: @Learner in that case, you'll keep failing interviews because you'll never be able to understand the concepts, keep viewing the *wrong* videos or misunderstand what they are saying. Never mind actually *using* those features in production. Even worse, a good interviewer will quickly find out that you don't really understand about replication

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Wrong videos? lol well I can't understand pluralsight videos, ideally none. Very complex explanations lol. Regarding interviewers, I agree, but 99% bad interviewers is what I found in industry.

Comment: @Learner in that case, good luck. You'll need it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I will try Pana :) :) Surely try to get my head around, for my bread lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options for database syncing in SQL server.

**1.** **SQL Server Always on Feature (SQL 2012 Onwards)** - By using this feature, You need to make a primary and secondary replica (could be multiple secondry replica), Once Always On feature is configured, the Second replicas automatically updated based on Primary replica updates. This also provides HADR feature, if the primary replica goes down, the secondary replica will be active and play primary replica role.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

**2. SQL Server Replication -** Merge replication, Transaction replication etc.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/types-of-replication?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 3):

1. CQRS is a pattern which dictates that the responsibility of *Command* and *Query* operations be seperated.
2. Now there are multiple ways you can sychronize the data between databases. You can use **Master-Slave Configuration** or **Oplog Replication Mechanism** or something very much specific to the database.
3. But what's more important here is to decide what strategy to use. Since, you are using CQRS pattern now you have more than one data store (write store, read store) and there are fair chances that these data stores are network partitioned. In which case you would have to decide what really matters to you the most **Consistency** or **Availabililty**, which is generally goverened by what businesses require.

So in general, what replication strategy is to be used depends on whether your businesses require **Consistency** or **Availabililty**.

**References**:

1. **CAP Theroem**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem
2. **Replication** (Driven by CAP Theorem): https://www.brianstorti.com/replication/

Comment: Nishant, thank you for sharing some of the wonderful insights, cheers, willr ead more through your links in the answer

Comment: This answer has little to do with replicating data across databases. That's something already covered by the replication features in all major databases.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Thank you, still some of the points here are new to me, good to know these terms and at least "something about everything" lol as I will be playing role of solution architect :)

Comment: Cool @Learner. If this post had helped you out with some insights please consider accepting this answer. Thank you.

Comment: @NishantJain: Thank you Nishant, it helped me definitely. Sorry I clicked other post as an answer. but yours is also great level of help for me. I gave thumbsup on your post.